# Is there a place where I can find all the community wiki questions for Apple.SE?

Tags: discussion

Pretty simple...I was just curious and didn't know where I could find all the CW question. Is there a place where I can find all the community wiki questions for Apple.SE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find them with the search function:

> [wiki:1 is:question closed:0](https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wiki%3a1%20is%3aquestion%20closed%3a0)

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks so much Kyle! You want to vote up my question? (since you answered it...)